# How to deal with HTTP 301 status code?

Tags: qt, network-programming

I am creating a small program that will pull information from a website in order to learn. Specifically, I am trying to pull the archived winning numbers from this lotto website.

https://www.ohiolottery.com/WinningNumbers/KenoDrawings/KenoDrawingsArchive.aspx?date=01%2f01%2f2010

Here is the code I currently have (with `QT += network` in the pro file):

Retriever.h

```
#ifndef RETRIEVER_H
#define RETRIEVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QDebug>

class Retriever : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Retriever(QObject *parent = 0);
    void fetch();

public slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager;
};

#endif // RETRIEVER_H
```

Retriever.cpp

```
#include "retriever.h"

Retriever::Retriever(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}


void Retriever::fetch()
{
    QString stackoverflow = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    QString lotto = "https://www.ohiolottery.com/WinningNumbers/KenoDrawings/KenoDrawingsArchive.aspx?date=01%2f01%2f2010";

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(lotto)));
}


void Retriever::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) qDebug() << "no error";
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

    qDebug() << reply->url();
    qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
    qDebug() << statusCode;

    if (reply->atEnd()) qDebug() << "already at end";

    while (!reply->atEnd()) {
        QByteArray data = reply->readLine();
        QString::fromUtf8(data.data(), data.size());
        QString str(data);
        qDebug() << str;
    }
}
```

When I run this with stackoverflow, it works fine. But when I run this with the lotto website, I get the following output from `qDebug`:

```
no error
QUrl("https://www.ohiolottery.com/WinningNumbers/KenoDrawings/KenoDrawingsArchive.aspx?date=01%2F01%2F2010")
QUrl("/mobile")
301
already at end
```

There seems to be a few issues. First, there is no error but it thinks its a mobile site? Then it thinks its already at the end of the content (I'm assuming that its because of 301 status code). I'm not familiar with retrieving information from websites, so I'm not sure how to deal with this error. I copied the url exactly from the website, so I don't know why its redirecting. How can I resolve this error? More specifically, how can I get the correct URL to give to the `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status `301` tells you have to fetch data from another url which in your case is `/mobile`.

You need to set `user-agent` request header to a web browser, because that website thinks you are a mobile client.

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(lotto));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader, QVariant("Mozilla/5.0 "));
manager->get(request);
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately I ended up with the same result. I also noticed that I was not able to set the `QUrl` to the `QNetworkRequest` via initialization. I got an error saying it wanted a class/struct/union. I had to use `QNetworkRequest::setUrl`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by setting the `user-agent` to `"Google Chrome"`